# Importing a 2d array into a class with delphi

Tags: arrays, class, delphi, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a class with a 2d array(arrscore) within the create method, I have done some research on this and this is as far as I have come.

`constructor create(spriority, sSelOne, sSeltwo, sSelthree: string; arrcountry: array of string; arrscore: array of real);`

Here is my declaration of my classes variables

```
type
  tMap = class
  private
    // variables
    priority, selone, seltwo, selthree: string;
    country: array of string;
    score: array of real;
```

This is my create code

```
 begin
  priority := spriority;
  selone := sSelOne;
  seltwo := sSeltwo;
  selthree := sSelthree;
  country := arrcountry;
  score := arrscore;
end;
```

This doesn't work as it is incompatible types of dynamic array and array of real.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any two-dimensional array. I see only two one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Don't pass open arrays by value. If you do then a copy is made and passed on the stack. This is inefficent and can lead to stack overflow. Use `const` parameters. What you then need to do is to replace the assignments to your dynamic arrays with code that allocates new arrays (use `SetLength`) and then to copy the values from the argument to your dynamic arrays in a loop. In modern Delphi you can use [`System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy) instead of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is rather annoying.

If you use [open array parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters), you traditionally have to copy the arrays the manual and tedious way:

```
var
  country: array of string; // dynamic array
  score: array of Real; // dynamic array

// open array parameters
constructor Create(...; const arrcountry: array of string; const arrscore: array of Real);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(country, Length(arrcountry));
  for i := 0 to High(arrcountry) do
    country[i] := arrcountry[i];
  // similarly for score/arrscore
end;
```

However, as [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) points out, recent Delphi versions also provide the [`TArray.Copy<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy) procedure:

```
SetLength(country, Length(arrcountry));
TArray.Copy<string>(arrcountry, country, Length(arrcountry));
SetLength(score, Length(arrscore));
TArray.Copy<Real>(arrscore, score, Length(arrscore));
```

But if you use [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) parameters instead, you can do

```
var
  country: TArray<string>; // dynamic array
  score: TArray<Real>; // dynamic array

// dynamic array parameters
constructor Create(...; arrcountry: TArray<string>; arrscore: TArray<Real>);
begin
  country := arrcountry;
  score := arrscore;
end;
```

Notice that the arrays will not be copied, so any change you make to `country` will affect the caller's array (because it is the same array).

If you want to copy, do

```
country := Copy(arrcountry);
score := Copy(arrscore);
```

Comment: "you have to copy the arrays the manual and tedious way" Not so in modern Delphi. See my comment to the Q

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for pointing out the `TArray.Copy<T>` procedure. I had completely forgotten about that one.